# Reverse engineering checksum from ascii string?

Tags: checksum, crc16

I'm currently working on reverse engineering a device I have serial protocol.

I'm mostly there however I can't figure out one part of the string.

For each string the machine returns it always has !XXXX where the XXXX varies in a hex value. From what I can find this may be CRC16?

However I can't figure out how to calculate the CRC myself to confirm it is correct.

Here's an example of 3 Responses.

```
U;0;!1F1B
U;1;!0E92
U;2;!3C09
```

The number can be replaced with a range of ascii characters. For example here's what I'll be using most often.

```
U;RYAN W;!FF0A
```

How do I calculate how the checksum is generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need more examples with different lengths.

With reveng, you will want to reverse the CRC byte, e.g. `1b1f`, not `1f1b`. It appears that the CRC is calculated over what is between the semicolons. With reveng I get that the polynomial is `0x1021`, which is a very common 16-bit polynomial, and that the CRC is reflected.

```
% reveng -w 16 -s 301b1f 31920e 32093c 5259414e20570aff
width=16  poly=0x1021  init=0x1554  refin=true  refout=true  xorout=0x07f0  check=0xfa7e  name=(none)
width=16  poly=0x1021  init=0xe54b  refin=true  refout=true  xorout=0xffff  check=0xfa7e  name=(none)
```

With more examples, you will be able to determine the initial value of the CRC register and what the result is exclusive-or'ed with.

Comment: Could you explain how you formatted this? Of `301b1f 31920e 32093c 5259414e20570aff`, what is the input and what is the output?

Comment: Each of those is a message with CRC appended. Look at the messages in the question and correlate them with those hex strings.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool available to reverse-engineer CRC calculations: CRC RevEng http://reveng.sourceforge.net/

You can give it hex strings of the input and checksum and ask it what CRC algorithm matches the input. Here is the input for the first three strings (assuming the messages are U;0;, U;1; and U;2;):

```
$ reveng -w 16 -s 553b303b1f1b 553b313b0e92 553b323b3c09 
width=16  poly=0xa097  init=0x63bc  refin=false  refout=false  xorout=0x0000  check=0x6327  residue=0x0000  name=(none)
```

The checksum follows the input messages. Unfortunately this doesn't work if I try the RYAN W message. You'll probably want to try editing the input messages to see which part of the string is being input into the CRC.

Comment: Thanks.
I found for the RYAN W it just seemed to cut off at U; when doing some experiments.

I had tried reveng but didn't quite know how to use it. Thanks for showing me how.